# Regular expression in MySQL to exclude something that has specific word inside brackets

Tags: mysql, regex

This regular expression is for a MySQL query.

I want to exclude the following row because it has `something` inside the bracket:

```
bla bla bla bla bla bla (bla bla bla something)
```

However I want to include the following row, because it does not have `something` inside the bracket:

```
bla bla bla (bla bla bla)
```

I tried this query but it didnt work.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field NOT REGEXP '((%something%))';
```

I think this is wrong. I just did trial and error. I like to use a regular expression, but I never understand it completely. Are there any good tutorials/books/links for learning the detail of regular expressions?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html is an excellent place to start.  But be aware that MySQL regexes are POSIX compliant, which means they're blazingly fast but they offer a very limited set of features compared to most of the other flavors covered there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field NOT REGEXP '\\([^\\)]*something.*\\)'
```

The regexp is:

```
\([^\)]*something.*\)
```

(but MySQL treats \ as a special character so we have to escape it as \).

That means:

```
\(         - an open-parentheses character ("(" has a special meaning
             in regular expressions, so we have to escape it with "\")
[^\)]      - any character except a ")"...
*          - ... repeated any number of times
something  - the string to match
.          - any character
*          - ... repeated any number of times
\)         - a ")" character
```

Comment: actually the answer before you was right '\(.*something.*\)'
but he deleted it

Comment: This one is actually slightly better, because `(.*something.*)` will also match `(otherstuff)   something   (otherstuff)` i.e. it can match even if the 'something' isn't inside `()`.

(It's possible to fool this one too, but only if you allow multiple levels of `()`).

Comment: yes im using that one, I feel bad that I said it didnt work. but I like your explainations to your answer. thanks!